I can't put a button to stop all sounds in my website, and when I try, all my Javascript code stops working
I'm making a soundboard dupe of YouTube in my classes of webdesign and I can't figure out how to code a button to stop all the sounds playing. I think it has something to do with the way I coded the function that makes the sounds play, but I really don't know how to change it in a way that makes it work.
So this is my code in Javascript:
function speelGeluid(welkGeluid){
        var audiootje = "Audio/" + welkGeluid;
        var audio = new Audio(audiootje);
        audio.play();
    }

And an example of the HTML part:
<div class="videotje" id="FunkyFrog1" onclick="speelGeluid ('TacoBell.mp3')"></div>

It took me and my teacher a few tries to figure out what works for playing the audio as well, but I don't know I can stop the sounds once they're playing. Everything I've tried has just made the entirety of the Javascript not work

I would assume that the issue is because you have no way to access the audio elements outside of the function which creates and plays them. I'd suggest you keep the references to them in an array, then when you want to stop them all playing, loop over that array and call stop() on each one.

To create a button that stops all the sounds playing, you need to keep track of the audio elements being played. You can do this by storing them in an array and then pausing them all when the stop button is clicked.
// Array to store all the audio elements
var playingAudios = [];

function speelGeluid(welkGeluid) {
    var audiootje = "Audio/" + welkGeluid;
    var audio = new Audio(audiootje);
    audio.play();
    playingAudios.push(audio);
}

function stopAllSounds() {
    playingAudios.forEach(function(audio) {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0; // Reset to start
    });
    playingAudios = []; // Clear the array
}




<div class="videotje" id="FunkyFrog1" onclick="speelGeluid('TacoBell.mp3')"></div>
<!-- Add this button to stop all sounds -->
<button onclick="stopAllSounds()">Stop All Sounds</button>


for(const audio of playingAudios) { ... } these days :)
